# How to append a value to a dictionary inside a dictionary (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, dictionary, caching

I'm trying to create a message cache that is structured as a dictionary like such...

```
var messageCache = [String:[String:Message]]()
```

It's basically [Conversation Id: [Message Id: Message]], and the Message is also a dictionary of values.

Whenever I want to add a new message object into the message cache I'm calling

```
let messageKey = snapshot.key
let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)

messageCache[convoId] = [messageKey:message]
```

However, I believe this erases everything inside messageCache[convoId] and replaces it with just that one message key and object. I've also tried the code below but it returns nil.

```
messageCache[convoId]?[messageKey] = message
```

How can I append to messageCache[convoId] another dictionary containing [messageKey:Message]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
typealias MessageCacheeValue = (String, Message)

var messageCache = [String:[MessageCacheeValue]]()

let messageKey = snapshot.key
let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)

let newValue = (messageKey, message)

if messageCache[convoId] == nil {
    messageCache[convoId] = [newValue]
} else {
    messageCache[convoId]?.append(newValue)
}
```

Now the messageCache is a dictionary of String keys and Values of tuple array.

Answer (score 0):

**Sol1**

```
var messageCache = [String:[String:Message]]()
messageCache[convoId].updateValue(message,forKey:messageKey)
```

**Sol2**

```
var messageCache = [String:[[String:Message]]]()
messageCache[convoId]?.append([messageKey:message])
```